# How to set wait Queue Multiple and Max Pool Size in application.properties for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, security, uri, properties-file

Recently move from local storage to a database located in linode. I'm moving all the projects there and now i have to use authentication for mongo Database. I used to use uri configuration:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/testDatabase?waitQueueMultiple=500&maxPoolSize=1000
```

In the uri i set 500 as Wait Queue Value and 1000 as Max Pool Size

Now Im using another config due to security:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=testDatabase
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=MySuperPassword
```

Exist any field where i can set wait queue an pool size values?

or

Can i set security config in the uri ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its a long time after asking the question but finally found the correct way to set this properties, hope this helps to someone with the same question :D

```
mongodb://user:password@ip:port/databaseName?authSource=admin&waitQueueMultiple=1000&maxPoolSize=1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set both user/password and extra properties in `spring.data.mongodb.uri`

`spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database` needs a separate property.

See [Connecting to a MongoDB Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) (it gives an example of replica set, but the principles still apply for the properties you want)

> You can set the spring.data.mongodb.uri property to change the URL and configure additional settings such as the replica set, as shown in the following example:
>   `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test`
>
> If you use the Mongo 3.0 Java driver, `spring.data.mongodb.host` and `spring.data.mongodb.port` are not supported. In such cases, `spring.data.mongodb.uri` should be used to provide all of the configuration.

see also https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html